# i want to add new row to datatable wiithout any effect for existing data

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code to bind the data to the datatable

```
dtPromotion = db.GetDatastrong text(drcheck["vb"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

[DataRow reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
//create the new row
DataRow newRow = dtPromotion.NewRow();

//Set the columns
newRow["Col1"] = "data";
newRow["Col2"] = "data";

//add the row to the data table
dtPromotion.Rows.Add(newRow);
```